# Error in imports pyCrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

My problem is the follow: I have installed pyCrypto in my computer. Then when I execute a script the intepreter say this:

```
from: can't read /var/mail/Crypto.Cipher
./entrega2.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token ('
./entrega2.py: line 2: obj=DES.new('abcdefgh', DES.MODE_ECB)'
```

It can't read from Crypto.Cipher. However if I execute the intepreter of python, then I can do this:

> > from Crypto.Cipher import AES

This sentence in the intepret runs but in a file not. I don't know why.

Sorry because my english is very bad and my skills low.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Please add the code of the script that you are trying to execute.

Comment: The code is the same:

Only the import :) i am new in python and cryptography and i was trying

Comment: it seems to me that the error is not related to the fact that the interpreter cannot read from Crypto.Cipher but more probably there is a typo in your source code. May you please post the lines surrounding `obj=DES.new('abcdefgh', DES.MODE_ECB)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you execute the script as `python entrega2.py`

Or

Add the following at the top of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```